# jquery ui star rating doesn't style radio box

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I want to add star-rating to my website.

Here is my cshtml markup

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "דירוג";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_SubPage.cshtml";
    ViewBag.Page = "Rating";
    ViewBag.TabHeader = "דירוג";
}


              @*=====css=====*@
            <link href="@Url.Content("~/Resources/jquery.ui.stars-3.0/jquery.ui.stars.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
            <link href="@Url.Content("~/Styles/Rating.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<form>
    Rating: <span id="stars-cap"></span>
    <div id="stars-wrapper1" class="span4 oofset3">
        <input type="radio" name="newrate" value="1" title="Very poor" />
        <input type="radio" name="newrate" value="2" title="Poor" />
        <input type="radio" name="newrate" value="3" title="Not that bad" />
        <input type="radio" name="newrate" value="4" title="Fair" />
        <input type="radio" name="newrate" value="5" title="Average" checked="checked" />
        <input type="radio" name="newrate" value="6" title="Almost good" />
        <input type="radio" name="newrate" value="7" title="Good" />
        <input type="radio" name="newrate" value="8" title="Very good" />
        <input type="radio" name="newrate" value="9" title="Excellent" />
        <input type="radio" name="newrate" value="10" title="Perfect" />
    </div>


</form>



    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Resources/jquery.ui.stars-3.0/jquery.ui.stars.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Rating.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And I get the following error in the browser Dev-console:

> ```
> jquery.ui.stars.js:20
>
> Uncaught TypeError: Object function (a,b){return new d.fn.init(a,b,g)} has no method 'widget'
>
> jquery-1.5.1.min.js:19
>
> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'on'
> ```

after changing to jquery 1.7.2 I get the following:

> ```
> jquery.ui.stars.js:20
>
> Uncaught TypeError: Object function (a,b){return new e.fn.init(a,b,h)} has no method 'widget'
>
> Rating.js:23
>
> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'stars'
> ```

In the UI I see the radio box and not the start.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems your star rating plugin is using the [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method to register event handlers. That method was introduced in jQuery 1.7, and you're using version 1.5.1, which does not support it.

Upgrading the jQuery library to the [latest release](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery#Current_Release) (currently 1.7.2) will probably solve your problem.

Comment: From the error messages, it looks like the star rating plugin also depends on the jQuery UI widget framework. You might want to include jQuery UI in your page.